# Javascript get progress from c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, progress

I have a MVC project, in my View i got a link to a Method in my Controller that returns a downloadable file.

My Method download data from various APIs and process the data to a file. This method takes 10-15min to complete.

I want to show progress in my View, what is the best way to do this? Should i use global variables in my controller that my method sets, and use async javascript loops to get these values?

Is there any good way to get progress from the api requests, i use the following methods for that:

```
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(DataValues.xx + "url/" + label + "/" + UUID + "?action=" + act);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(DataValues.user, DataValues.password);
    httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: save your state into a session variable, and use ajax every x seconds to query the state, then, update the view ;-)

Comment: Your API methods would somehow have to periodically send a status (in terms of a percentage or something), then you'd need to poll in jQuery for updates (or if you're using HTML5, leverage server sent events).

Answer (score 1):

For REALLY long running processes, you could consider using something like SignalR to send back status updates.

So - rather than clicking on a link to demand a file (and having the browser sit there for 10 mins waiting for a response)  you could have:

1. The link poking the mvc controller "I want this, let me know when
   you've got it" (which hooks up the SignalR side of things)
2. Server process downloads content - as it comes down you keep a track
   of how    much so far and broadcast progress...
3. The browser-side signalR consumes this broadcast ("x bytes found" or
   similar - i.e "I've done X much") - view updates accordingly.
4. Once the process is complete the server broadcasts sends an "all done, come and get it" where the browser then downloads the results.

(In the final bit, you might even be able to send the found content directly back via signalR, but you might bump into issues around size of data limits / constraints).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible with signalr, but using something like XSockets and their long running controller sounds more suitable. First of all since that process it very long running, but also since it can send data to any specific client with status/info.
http://xsockets.net/docs/4/controllers

Another reason is that XSockets supports binary data which signalr does not.
I think XSockets latest version is commercial, but the previous version is free to use.